# "railroad flat" meaning in context

Tags: phrases

From The Godfather:

> He left the club an caught a cab to his furnished room on Tenth
>   Avenue. He boarded with an Italian family to which he was distantly
>   related. His two room was separated from the rest of their *railroad*
>   *flat* by a special door.

So, I'm confused by the "railroad flat" phrase. Is railroad the same as railway here?

Comment: Din't you even try a [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/railroad%20flat)? :)

Comment: @MaulikV I tried, of course. But not this one. In any way, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same term as "railroad apartment" ("flat" is another term for "apartment", nowadays more often used in Britain), so called because of the similarity of the layout to a railroad car.  See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_apartment).